# Does anyone know of a asynchronous mysql lib for python?

Tags: python, mysql, twisted, asynchronous, tornado

I've been looking into non-blocking servers for python (tornado, twisted etc) but a lot of the benefits seems to be lost if there's no non-blocking connection to the database. Does anyone know if there are any projects that take care of this? (by non-blocking a la node.js)

Edit: Clarified my question

Answer (score 13):

You can use Twisted's [ADBAPI](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.html) to wrap a synchronous DBAPI implementation.

E.g.:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

def result(rows):
    for row in rows:
        print row

    reactor.stop()

def fail(err):
    err.printDetailedTraceback()
    reactor.stop()

pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('sqlite3', 'animals.db')
d = pool.runQuery('SELECT * FROM animals', ())
d.addCallbacks(result, fail)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out our new [txMySQL project](https://github.com/hybridlogic/txMySQL) which can do this now.

This is a native asynchronous implementation of the binary MySQL protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The way you do that is by spawning database queries in a separate thread. With Twisted you can use `deferToThread()` or `deferToThreadPool()` (see the API docs[1](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html)).

Comment: Additionally, twisted.enterprise.adbapi provides a DB-API-like API on top of `deferToThreadPool` specifically to make it easier to access MySQL and other rdbms in a Twisted-based application.